# What happens to the Governor and the troops which finally took over the village?

Tags: realm-of-empires

I attacked a village and took it over. The governor and troops have gone missing. What happened to them ?

Answer (score 2):

GOVERNOR: He takes over the village, becomes the administrator there. In other words, he 'disappears' and you cannot use him to attack another village.

TROOPS: The troops stay there as support and defend the village. Like ordinary support, these troops can be sent back/recalled.